# After Load Complete, Do Something in All Loaded HTML Files

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a radio button, it loads a external HTML file and this file loads 12 other HTML files or some parts of that files. All those HTML files contain some input fileds. I set all input fields an id automaticlly and I'm OK here whit this code.

```
$('input').each(function() {
  var thisIs = $(this).closest(".loadFileHere").attr("name")
  $(this).attr("id", parentId + thisIs + $(this).val());
});
$('form').each(function() {
  var thisIs = $(this).closest(".loadFileHere").attr("name")
  $(this).attr("id", parentId + thisIs + "Form");
});
```

To do that, I need to replace very same code block, which is above, in each load function, which is below, as complete.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[class^="radioActivate"]', function(){
  var radioValue = this.value;
  var parentId = $(this).closest('.section').attr('id');
  var direction = $("#" + parentId).find(".barOptions").attr('id');
  if (radioValue == "Active") {
    $("#" + parentId).find("#" + direction).load("includes/7_preference/modules/" + parentId + ".html", function(){
      $("#" + parentId + "Position").load("includes/4_block/position.html);
      // and 11 more load functions are here
    });
  } else $("#" + direction).children().remove();
});
```

Just to keep the file size as smaller as possible, I wish to use that code only one time after all loading prosecces completed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function setIds(parentId) {
    $('input, form').each(function() {
      var thisIs = $(this).closest(".loadFileHere").attr("name")
      $(this).attr("id", parentId + thisIs + $(this).val());
    });
    $('form').each(function() {
      var thisIs = $(this).closest(".loadFileHere").attr("name")
      $(this).attr("id", parentId + thisIs + "Form");
    });
}
```

And then you can call this in each `onchange`: `setIds(parentId);`